# unable to read SMS from a Nokia X2-00 using AT commands in hyperterminal

Tags: nokia, at-command

In my project, i want to read SMS from phone using AT commands.  Iam using Nokia X2-00 for that.  I can send SMS, but i can't read SMS.  It shows "ERROR"

commands entered in hyperterminal

```
AT
OK

AT+CMGF=1
OK

AT+CPMS=?
ERROR

AT+CMGL="ALL"
ERROR
```

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last two commands is not correct i use following commands to send the msg from Nokia X2-01 this may help you..!

**AT+CMGF=1

AT+CSCA="+92XXXXXXXXXX"// message service number
AT+CMGS="+92XXXXXXXXXX" //sender number

> IT IS VERY EASY

+CMGS: 6
OK**